# Full Calendar.io - Execution my `eventAfterAllRender` only once on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, dynamic-content

I am using `eventRender` to create my events on FullCalendar. Afterwards, I run `eventAfterAllRender` to dynamically create checkboxes based on the classes on each event. For example, an event can look like this:

**Event HTML**

```
<td class="fc-event-container filterable-item">
  <a class="group1-red group2-smith group3-tuesday" href="#">
    <div class="fc-content">
       <!-- generated automatically -->
    </div>
  </a>
</td>
```

After the events rendered, my function will then look at the classes prefaced with `group#-`, split that part and generate checkboxes with values equal to the class. These checkboxes look like this:

**Checkbox HTML**

```
<li>
  <input class="content__criteria" type="checkbox" name="group1" id="group1-red" data-identifier="red">
  <label for="group1-red">Red</label>
</li>
```

---

Here is where my issue begins, I am filtering my events by calling `RerenderEvents` on my Checkbox Change event handler.

**Checkbox Calls**

```
$('.content__criteria').on('change', function(e){
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
});
```

When this rerenders, it destroys my checkbox on rerender which then breaks my calendar. I'm looking for a way I can make sure my `eventAfterAllRender` only counts for the first render, or the one time on load.

This is a trimmed down version of my app:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: '',
          center: 'title',
          right: ''
      },
      eventRender: function (event, eventElement){
        // adds classes to calendar events
        // adds array to handle the show and hide of the elements
      }, 
      eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
        // code to dynamically generate checkboxes
        generateCheckboxes();
      }
});
```

---

**Things I know:**
- I know my filter method works, since it was working when I had the hardcoded checkboxes in

- I know my function to create an array of objects (to show, vs hide) is working
- I know `eventAfterAllRender` is running every time on click of the checkbox

**Things I need help with**

- Setting that method of `eventAfterAllRender` to only run once (not everytime `eventRender` or `rerenderEvents` is called.

Appreciate any help on this!
Thanks!

Comment: you can't change how often the callback executes, fullCalendar controls that, but you could set a flag in your code so it doesn't run generateCheckboxes more than once. Although if your list of events changes presumably you do need to do something to add a new checkbox or remove one, or change its description?

Comment: @ADyson the list wouldn't specifically be changing by adding new/destroying some after the initial load. I tried wrapping it in a function similar to [this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once), but to no avail. I'll keep looking into adding a check to see if it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the eventAfterAllRender callback from firing every time the calendar updates, but you can set a simple flag to stop your own checkbox function from executing more than once:

```
checkboxesGenerated = false; //initialise flag variable

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
          left: '',
          center: 'title',
          right: ''
      },
      eventRender: function (event, eventElement){
        // adds classes to calendar events
        // adds array to handle the show and hide of the elements
      }, 
      eventAfterAllRender: function(view){
        // code to dynamically generate checkboxes, only runs if the flag is false
        if (checkboxesGenerated == false) {
          checkboxesGenerated = true; //set the flag for future reference
          generateCheckboxes();
        }
      }
});
```